# How to Coalesce datetime values from 3 columns into a single column in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, function, datetime, python-datetime

I have a dataframe with 3 date columns in datetime format:

| CLIENT_ID | DATE_BEGIN | DATE_START | DATE_REGISTERED |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-01 |
| 2 | 2020-01-02 | 2020-02-01 | 2020-01-01 |
| 3 | NaN | 2020-05-01 | 2020-04-01 |
| 4 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-01 | NaN |

How do I create (coalesce) a new column with the earliest datetime for each row resulting in an `ACTUAL_START_DATE`

| CLIENT_ID | DATE_BEGIN | DATE_START | DATE_REGISTERED | ACTUAL_START_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-01 |
| 2 | 2020-01-02 | 2020-02-01 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-01 |
| 3 | NaN | 2020-05-01 | 2020-04-01 | 2020-04-01 |
| 4 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-02 | NaN | 2020-01-01 |

some sort of variation with `bfill`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, a mix of `bfill` and `ffill` on the axis columns should do it:

```
df.assign(ACTUAL_START_DATE = df.filter(like='DATE')
                                .bfill(axis=1)
                                .ffill(axis=1)
                                .min(axis=1)
        )
 
   CLIENT_ID  DATE_BEGIN  DATE_START DATE_REGISTERED ACTUAL_START_DATE
0          1  2020-01-01  2020-01-01      2020-01-01        2020-01-01
1          2  2020-01-02  2020-02-01      2020-01-01        2020-01-01
2          3         NaN  2020-05-01      2020-04-01        2020-04-01
3          4  2020-01-01  2020-01-01             NaN        2020-01-01
```